# How to post Json Array using retrofit in android?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

I am not able to post Json array from my add to cart list using retrofit. User will choose the products and then add to cart. Ineed save that data using sqlite db. Final order confirm state - I want to send all products (list) to server like this format code. I searched on google and can't find any solution.

```
JsonArray datas = new JsonArray();
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();

[
    {
        "name": "Phone",
        "quantity": 50,
        "price": 30000
    },
    {
        "name": "Computer",
        "quantity": 10,
        "price": 15000
    }
]
```

Comment: Check my answer on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743550/how-can-send-arraylist-data-from-volley-request-and-get-in-php/42000668#42000668 you can do this in retrofit. I have send json array as a string

Comment: check here you might get idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820740/how-to-post-json-array-using-retrofit-2

Answer (score 0):

this is very simple just do like this:-

```
@POST("yourApiEndPoint")
Call<YourPojoClass> yourMethodName(@Query("data") JSONArray jsonArray);
```

Comment: why `@Query`? this probably should be `@Body`.

Comment: in my case, I am only sending a single parameter then why I create a class for a single parameter. if I have many parameters then I should have to create a class and send it in Body. If you have only one parameter you can also send in Query

Comment: A body post is not the same as a query param